# How to use bazel for google test

Tags: bazel, googletest

I'm trying to use bazel for my project.
I'm following the tutorial (http://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-bazel.html).

```
~/gtest-playground$ ls -lR
.:
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 name name  296 Jan  1 09:54 WORKSPACE
drwxrwxr-x 2 name name 4096 Jan  1 09:54 test

./test:
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 name name 130 Jan  1 09:54 BUILD
-rw-rw-r-- 1 name name 222 Jan  1 09:54 test.cc
```

All the files are directly copied and pasted from above link.

But when I `bazel build` it, it fails with the following error message.

```
~/gtest-playground$ bazel build //test:hello_test 
ERROR: /home/name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_name/51f23e39be363c4e226bf6cdc66908fe/external/com_google_googletest/BUILD.bazel:44:1: no such package '@platforms//os': The repository '@platforms' could not be resolved and referenced by '@com_google_googletest//:windows'
DEBUG: Rule 'com_google_googletest' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "755f9a39bc7205f5a0c428e920ddad092c33c8a1b46997def3f1d4a82aded6e1"
DEBUG: Call stack for the definition of repository 'com_google_googletest' which is a http_archive (rule definition at /home/name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_name/51f23e39be363c4e226bf6cdc66908fe/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:237:16):
 - /home/name/gtest-playground/WORKSPACE:3:1
ERROR: Analysis of target '//test:hello_test' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.139s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

My current bazel version is:

```
~/gtest-playground$ bazel --version
bazel 0.27.1
```

And I confirm it doesn't work higher bazel version.

I'm wondering how should I resolve the platform issue here?

Comment: Do you have a `test` folder?

Comment: @Vertexwahn You could repro with code here: https://github.com/dentiny/bazel-playground

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of the Bazel warning ("indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments") you can modify the WORKSPACE file this way:

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_google_googletest",
    sha256 = "53de8c75150430c217550ec6bb413029300120407f2de02ea8e20e89675f5e94",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-912db742531bf82efb01194bc08140416e3b3467",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/912db742531bf82efb01194bc08140416e3b3467.tar.gz",
    ],
)
```

From the GitHub GoogleTest website:

```
The 1.12.x branch will be the last to support C++11. Future releases will require at least C++14.
```

You need to ensure that when Bazel is invoked via `bazel test` that the C++ compiler supports C++11 and up.

E.g. `bazel test --cxxopt=-std=c++20 //...` for Ubuntu 11 with GCC 11.

You can also create a `.bazelrc` file that contains different configurations, e.g.:

*.bazelrc*:

```
# GCC 11.2
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-std=c++20
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Wall
build:gcc11 --define compiler=gcc11
```

You can now run your test via `bazel test --config=gcc11 //...`

Here is a demo of how to use GoogleTest with a Bazel config:
https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/main/third_party_libraries/cpp/GoogleTest

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation! Could you please tell me your bazel version? I found it work for bazel 1.0.0.

Comment: I used Bazel 6.0.0, but should work also with 5.x and 4.x and maybe earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

Bazel 0.27.1 is very old. Use a newer version. (6.0.0 was just released.)

Comment: I tried with 6.0.0, get the same result.

Comment: You could try with this code: https://github.com/dentiny/bazel-playground. It's fairly simple.

Comment: I'm able to get a compilation error from C++ with `bazel test //...` in that repository using Bazel 6.

Comment: I guess that might be what I see. Nice!